# Heroku Postgres connection capped at 5/20

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra, puma

I have a Sinatra app running on Heroku free plan with Postgres, and I tried to set the database connection to 20 but after I pushed and run `heroku pg:info` the connection is still 5/20. It also wouldn't use all 20 connections even if I try to to a loader.io load test on it.

So I wonder what could I do to make it utilize all the 20 available connections or I am having some misunderstanding here?

```
# database.yml (for ActiveRecord)
production:
   adapter: postgresql
   encoding: unicode
   database: mydb
   username: <%= ENV['PG_USER'] %>
   password: <%= ENV['PG_PASS'] %>
   pool: <%= ENV['DB_POOL'] || ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 20 %>

# Procfile
web: bundle exec puma -t 5:20 -p $PORT

# puma.rb
preload_app!

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end

# config.ru
require_relative './config/init'
use Rack::SSL if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'production'
run Sinatra::Application
```

The `DB_POOL` variable has been set to 20 on Heroku but it still doesn't do anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where in the Heroku/database provider's docs does it say you get 20?

Comment: @iain running `heroku pg:info` always show that I am only using 5/20 of my total connections. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-plans#hobby-tier also says my hobby-dev plan should allow 20 maximum connections.

Comment: How did you test the DB connections? I mean, getting Puma to spin up a new thread just means a new connection but I suspect you'd need to make each call to Postgres long running or you won't use up the pool, I'll gues that without needing the connection it will drop back into the pool and remain as near minimum as possible (that's how pools are generally written). Try writing a really slow query and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @iain I updated the code to include my config.ru and puma.rb file since I guess they are relevant to starting puma. Can you find any problem in these? I really have no idea now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by running puma with `-C config/puma.rb`

Comment: Glad you got it fixed.